# How do you read individual cUrl chunks?

Tags: python, ruby, bash, curl

Is there any way to download from a url and saving each individual chunk as it comes back from the server to separate file for analysis?

I have a problem when I think the server is chopping the end of json output but the company we are getting the responses from are saying "no it's not"

when we curl on the terminal it stops at what I think is a chunk and hitting enter returns more data, is that definitely a chunk?

Otherwise I'd like to find a script that would save each chunk to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on examples from the [docs for pycurl.Curl() object](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from contextlib import closing as C

import pycurl

class Writer:
   def __init__(self, file):
       self.file = file

   def write(self, data):
       sys.stderr.write(data)
       self.file.write(data)

   def close(self):
       self.file.close()

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909710/'
with C(pycurl.Curl()) as c, C(Writer(open('output','wb'))) as w:
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, w.write)
    c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
    c.perform()
    print >>sys.stderr, c.getinfo(c.HTTP_CODE), c.getinfo(c.EFFECTIVE_URL)
```

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech: `w.write()` gets called by libcurl as soon as there is data received that needs to be saved. It can be 1 byte, it can be 100KB. Inside this function you can aggregate/slice it to get your chunks (whatever chunk means). I've added `sys.stderr.write(data)` that you can see the data as it arrives.

Comment: by chunks, I mean buffering from the server side.

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech: You could use [chunked-server.py](https://gist.github.com/cf1f475e0e65abfc5d58) to check that the above `pycurl` code does receive data in "chunks".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make curl do what you want it to (I don't even think it is possible using the BSD socket API), but I think I can help you debug your problem.

What I think you want is a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) that will allow you to inspect packet contents, and see exactly what happens "on the wire".

Comment: how does curl return separate chunks? does it send an escape character between chunks? would that explain why it stops at what I think is a chunk.

Comment: I don't think curl returns separate chunks at all. TCP connections have no concept of chunks, just streams and windows.